# coordinating two celery tasks

Tags: python, django, parallel-processing, celery

I have two tasks that are called in pairs. They are separate tasks because they talk to separate blocking i/o resources, and one of them (TaskA) exits early on the condition that a previous instances of the task pair is still running, while TaskB will still run (ie TaskA cares about overlapping task pairs, TaskB does not).

Right now I am looking at using cached tokens as per the cookbook example to enforce the rules laid out

```
def TaskA()
   take TaskA token
   exit if already taken
   check if TaskB token is taken
   exit if TaskB token is taken
   continue working

def TaskB()
   take TaskB token
   if token taken exit
   do task
```

Problem with this is that within a pair of TaskA and TaskB, if TaskB starts first, TaskA will mistakenly exit. If I can enforce that TaskA will always start first, then maybe this is an ok way to do it.

Otherwise:
My thoughts on this was to generate a rand() or timestamp in the calling function which would pass it to both tasks instances. TaskB instance would append it to the token it takes, and TaskA would use it to ignore the TaskB token if the rand portion matches its own, and exits if the token is taken, but the rand portion does not match.

```
def TaskA(rand)
   take TaskA token
   exit if already taken
   check if TaskB_* token is taken
   exit if TaskB_not_rand token is taken
   continue working

def TaskB(rand)
   check TaskB_* token
   if TaskB_* token taken exit
   take TaskB_rand token
   do task
```

Given the problem laid out, is using tokens in the manner I suggested in the second version (with rand() appended) the right way to get the tasks to coordinate? Or is there an easier method.

If the problem is not clear, or your mind is burning with curiosity as to why the tasks have this operational criteria, I can add more information.

Comment: I won't be able to use memcached if I want to search for prefixes on cached tokens.

Answer (score 1):

What about, instead of using random/timestamp, using a sequence number, so:

```
def TaskA():
  take TaskA_token
  exit if TaskA_token taken
  take TaskB_token
  if TaksB_token.sequence <= self.sequence:
    exit
```

Comment: Should be <, not <=.  You want the task pair to run when they are equal.